# Can you edit iMessages send with a subject line?

Tags: macos, ios, messages

Normally, when I send an iMessage, I can long tap (iOS) or right click (macOS) to bring up a menu and edit the message (as long as the message was sent in the last 15 minutes).

[image]

However, when I send an iMessage *with a subject line*, this feature isn't available.

[image]

Why is this? Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but where do you have a *subject line* in Messages?

Comment: @Allan “Show Subject Field” is an option in Settings > Messages on iOS. Don’t think it’s an option on macOS

Comment: Thanks!  I must have skipped over the setting a zillion times as I edit my blocked numbers all the time.  I am going to try and replicate the issue.

Comment: Confirmed.  If it as a subject line, you can only unsend it, but without a subject, you can edit.